# When did the Battle of Badr take place?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

When did the Battle of Badr take place? How many Muslims fought with the prophet (PBUH)? How many disbelievers took part in the battle? And who was their leader?

Comment: These are all trivial details that you can easily find by doing some research on your own.

Comment: Also, see this for more detailed understandings:  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Badr#:~:text=Muhammad%20was%20able%20to%20gather,170%20men%20from%20the%20Khazraj.

Answer (score -2):

On March 13, 624, Mohammed led Muslims to victory in the Battle of Badr, Saudi Arabia. The armies involved were not large: fewer than 400 Muslims and around 1,000 Meccan fighters. Despite the superior numbers of the Meccan forces (about 1,000 men), the Muslims scored a complete victory.